# Is there a simple uncertainty-principle explanation for the quantum noise limit of an amplifier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, noise

The quantum noise limit of a microwave amplifier's effective noise temperature, $T_N$, is found by setting $k_B T_N=hf/2$, where $f$ is the frequency of the detected radiation. This may be off by a factor of 2, I'm not sure.

There are lengthy and very detailed discussions of this online, e.g. at https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4729 which is written for quantum field theory experts. But for non-experts, is there a simple derivation of the quantum amplifier noise formula that is based on the uncertainty principle? I'm hoping for something deeper than just saying that the noise limit comes from quantum fluctuations with a zero-point energy scale of $hf/2$. It seems like the explanation must have something to do with the $\Delta E \Delta t$ uncertainty relationship, but I am having trouble seeing clearly how this comes about. Can the uncertainty principle be used to derive $k_B T_N=hf/2$? If so, what would $\Delta t$ correspond to, and why? And in this context, what is the role of amplifier gain in determining the quantum noise limit?